# In Rails with carrierwave how can we upload to two places one at a time (the second only if needed)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Here's what I need to do :

1. Upload a file to the local storage and send it to admins for approval
2. If admins approve, (as soon as the admins hit the approve button) the file should go to S# and will be served from there after that.

I need to do this in order to reduce costs. If someone upload a large number of useless files, I can't put them directly to S3 if they are going to be rejected anyway.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved i dont see much of issue here
which gem (paperclip or carriwave) are you Using for uploading file depending on you have to do the following stuff

i am assuming there is a user who uploads file an the admin has to approve it so that it can be displayed or stored in to s3

Which ever gem you use ,it stores the uploded file in public folder by default and in a file structure which determines for  which record the image belongs.

You have to write a functionality in you admin to fetch the record and get the image url and the use that image url to upload images to s3 if the admin approves it .

If you can give me the flow  how current system is running it would be much more better

Comment: Sure. Actually I think this is what you meant by saying the 'flow'. A user first uploads a bunch of images. The system will store them in the local machine. Then he will be taken to a page where he add a title and description for each of the images. Then he submit them. The admin check the images. If he reject the image will be deleted. If he accept the image will be sent to S3.

Comment: Store the images from user in local then you will have to write a functionality in admin (ie approve and reject).
Get the the user record ,you will get the image url stored in local from it and use that url to upload in s3

**Ref** : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

so your approve action would be something like this like

def approve
@user = User.find(parmas[:id])
bucket = s3.buckets.create('my-bucket')
obj = bucket.objects['key']
obj.write(Pathname.new(@user.url_path ))
#rest of the tings ...
end

Answer (score 0):

Store the images from user in local then you will have to write a functionality in admin (ie approve and reject).
Get the the user record ,you will get the image url stored in local from it and use that url to upload in s3

**Ref** : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

so your approve action would be something like this like

```
def approve
  @user = User.find(parmas[:id])
  bucket = s3.buckets.create('my-bucket')
  obj = bucket.objects['key']
 obj.write(Pathname.new(@user.url_path ))
end
```